# C# - Gradient over picture in picturebox

Tags: c#, gradient, picturebox

I have developed an application in VB.NET that I'm now moving over to C#.

Everything is going smooth so far, but I'm facing one problem.

I have a pictureBox that has a picture in it. Over this picture box I want a gradient to be that goes from transparent at top down to the color "control" to blend in with the forms background color. I have allready done this in VB.net which works, but when im trying to do this in C# the gradient seems to be drawn, but behind the picture.

Here is what i have tried:

```
private void PictureBox1_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Color top = Color.Transparent;
    Color bottom = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Control);

    GradientPictureBox(top, bottom, ref PictureBox1, e);
}

public void GradientPictureBox(Color topColor, Color bottomColor, ref PictureBox PictureBox1, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
    LinearGradientMode direction = LinearGradientMode.Vertical;
    LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(PictureBox1.DisplayRectangle, topColor, bottomColor, direction);
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, PictureBox1.DisplayRectangle);
    brush.Dispose();
}
```

However this does in fact seem to work, but again it paints the gradient behind the picture. In VB.net it painted it on top of the picture without any extra code..

Do i need to add anything extra?

If it matters im coding in C# 2010 express.

Comment: It doesn't seem likely that the language switch itself would cause this. An executing program doesn't know what language it was originally written in. Can you post your original VB.NET code?

Comment: Posted code worked fine.

Comment: Why you pass PictureBox1 by ref?

Comment: Alessandro D'Andria - To make the code ready for later use with more than one pictureBox.. But due to it not working the code within the void is not ready for it yet as i see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code does it.

I would perhaps consider making this its own control, and using the following code as its Paint event.

```
    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image, 0, 0, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        Color top = Color.FromArgb(128, Color.Blue);
        Color bottom = Color.FromArgb(128, Color.Red);
        LinearGradientMode direction = LinearGradientMode.Vertical;
        LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(pictureBox1.ClientRectangle, top, bottom, direction);

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle);
    }
```

This code produces the following image

[image]

Comment: Hmm the only real difference i see is that ClientRectangle is used instead of DisplayRectangle. However i cant get it to work

Comment: There has to be some other rendering code happening in your code then.  Did you override the OnPaintBackground event by any chance?  I produced the transparent gradient over the image by 1) Adding a new form to my project, 2) Dropping a picturebox onto it from the toolbox, 3) Registering the Paint event in my form and using the above code.  Try the above steps and it will work.

Comment: Change your top and bottom Colors and dont forget to set the transparency so you can see your "background image".  Color.Transparent and Color.Control as your gradient colors produces a gradient that is very hard to even see.  Try using:
Color top = Color.FromArgb(128, Color.Blue);
Color bottom = Color.FromArgb(128, Color.Red);

Comment: Sorry i have been busy lately but im looking at it now! And thanks for your time! How do i "3) Registering the Paint event in my form" because that must be where im missing it ..

Comment: I got it to work. All i had to do was add the line of 
`PictureBox1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.PictureBox1_Paint);`
to the events happening at form load. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would, but i cant since i need 15 reputation before i can :(